# i8042 no controller not found Oracle linux

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

my server installed Oracle-Linux  7.4 . 
it worked till yesterday but today when i restart this server, it has an issue : 
my error code is :

> i-8042 no controller not found

i need some helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovery from i8042 no controller found during boot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/765099/recovery-from-i8042-no-controller-found-during-boot)

Comment: i have still not found the answer, please help me

Answer (score 0):

i8042 is the chip that controls the PS/2 style keyboard and mouse ports. (In practice, on modern systems it is just a tiny corner in the south bridge chip that emulates a real Intel 8042 keyboard controller chip.)

If your server does not have those ports, then that message is harmless.

Most enterprise distributions still include PS/2 keyboard support in the kernel, so the message can be expected unless you use a custom kernel that has the legacy hardware support stripped off.

Comment: my server is stuck, i dont know how to get rid of this

Comment: okay, what is the hardware model of your server? Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Restart the server (by using the reset or power button if necessary), and when the system reaches the GRUB bootloader prompt, edit the default boot settings: remove the "rhgb" and "quiet" options, then let the system boot with the modified settings. You should now get a lot more messages. Is it still getting stuck immediately after the "i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found" message, or are there other messages after that? If there are no other messages after that, then it might be a system board failure: check for warranty and other hardware support options from your HW vendor.